# Rest Service in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, rest

I have a Rest Service in Visual Studio (C#). Initially it was working . But When I add a new Rest method, solution build is successful. But when we try to call the old REST methods in the project (for example POST) it is giving me 500 internal server error.

In firebug this what I found:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{73793b55-dcc3-45d3-ae2c-eaeb48dfe0f8} Line Number
>   1, Column 1:

But if I remove my newly added Rest service method, everything works fine.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: post the newly added method / interface definition

Answer (score 0):

Probably an interface mismatch between the client and the server. Did you rebuild both the client and the server with the new method definitions?

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: actually a comment, but I can only comment with >50 rep